# Android: App keeps prepopulating the sqlite database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, sharedpreferences

I currently have an activity that contains a shared preference to tell whether the sqlite database has been pre populated or if it needs to be. However my application populates every time the activity is created.

I currently have the following methods for the shared preferences:

```
public void checkDB() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = MainActivity.this
                .getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("CHECK", true); // Storing boolean - true/false
        editor.commit(); // commit changes
        prepopulate();

    }

    public void isChecked() {
        boolean setup = false;
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = MainActivity.this
                .getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        setup = sharedPref.getBoolean("CHECK", true); // getting boolean
        if (setup = false) {
            checkDB();
        } else {

        }
```

Here is how I call them in the onCreate method:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        checkDB();
        isChecked();
        loadListView();
        registerListClickCallback();
```

I am sure I have something wrong with one of the booleans in the shared preferences methods. Just incase it helps, here is my loop for pre populating the database fields:

```
public void prepopulate() {
        Locker setup = new Locker(this);
        for (int x = 0; x < 46; x++) {
            setup.open();
            String lockerNumber = "Locker" + x;
            setup.createLockerEntry(lockerNumber, 0);
            setup.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have setup = sharedPref.getBoolean("CHECK", true); I do think that the default value should be false. Also it should be if(setup == false) or if(!setup)

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `checkDB()` method in `isChecked()` method, hence you dont need to call it `onCreate()`

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        openedLockers = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOpenLockers);
        closedLockers = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bClosedLockers);
        openedLockers.setOnClickListener(this);
        closedLockers.setOnClickListener(this);
        checkDB();                                      // remove or comment this line 
        isChecked();
        loadListView();
        registerListClickCallback();
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the re-population is that you call `checkDB()` unconditionally as mentioned in @Kedamath.

However, consider using just plain old `SQLiteOpenHelper` and put any prepopulation code in its `onCreate()`. The framework calls that method exactly once when the database file didn't exist and the tables and any prepopulated data need to be created.